# babel: Mixing English and Chinese Using Google NotoFonts

Tags: luatex, fontspec, texlive, babel, cjk

### Goal

- My goal is to have a document that contains two languages, **English** and **(simplified) Chinese**.
- Both languages will appear in an equal amount (**one paragraph English** and then **one paragraph Chinese**).
- I compile with **LuaLaTeX** using **TeXLive**.
- I want to use the **Noto** font that is provided by **Google**.
- Later I want to use a KOMA document class (and not a Chinese-specific document class).

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
% babelprovide for *english* (default language of the document)
\babelprovide[
    main,
    import,
    language = Default]
    {english}

% babelprovide for *chinese-simplified*
\babelprovide[
    import,
    language = Chinese Simplified]
    {chinese-simplified}

%% Choose actual fonts for different font variants.
% Font for font variant "rm" (Serif)
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
% Font for font variant "sf" (Sans Serif --> Without Serif)
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
% Font for font variant "chinese-simplified"
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%% English -------------------------
\selectlanguage{english}

\section{Test}

\textbf{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
Test

%% Chinese -------------------------
\selectlanguage{chinese-simplified}

\section{杂杂杂}

\textbf{文文文文文文文文}
\begin{itemize}
\item 图图图图图图
\item 中中中中中中
\item 杂杂杂杂杂杂
\end{itemize}
文文文文文文文文

%% English -------------------------
\selectlanguage{english}

\section{Test}

\textbf{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

### TeXLive Font Status

I have several Noto font folders in my TeXLive installation. I assume that the `opentype` folders are used when I use LuaLaTeX.

- `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\google\noto`
- `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\tfm\google\noto`
- `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\truetype\google\noto`
- `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\google\noto`
- `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\google\notocjksc` (Chinese Fonts)

[image]

[image]

### Log File

```
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3785.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3790.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3795.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3800.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3830.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3855.
))
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/Biest/.texlive2019/texmf-
var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSerif(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Serif' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Latin,Language=Default].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"

(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+
smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tli
g;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerif/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tli
g;+smcp;"


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSans(0)' created for font 'Noto Sans'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Latin,Language=Default].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+s
mcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;
+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSans/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig
;+smcp;"


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansMono/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansMono/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSansMono(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Sans Mono' with options
(fontspec)             [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=WordS
pace,Script=Latin,Language=Default].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansMono:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansMono:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+smc
p;"
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansMono/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansMono/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+s
mcp;"
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

 (./test.aux

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSerifCJKSC/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSerifCJKSC/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSerifCJKSC/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | aux : font no 55 (nil) does not define feature smcp for script hani
 with language zhs

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSerifCJKSC(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Serif CJK SC' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Simplified,Language=Chinese
(fontspec)             Simplified].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSerifCJKSC:mode=node;script=hani;language=ZHS;+tl
ig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font NotoSan
sCJKSC not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!


luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0

Package fontspec Warning: Font "NotoSansCJKSC" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Simplified".

luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0

Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Chinese Simplified' not available for font
(fontspec)                'NotoSansCJKSC' with script ''.

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansCJKSC/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansCJKSC/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansCJKSC/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!


luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSansCJKSC(0)' created for font 'Noto
(fontspec)             Sans CJK SC' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Simplified,Language=Chinese
(fontspec)             Simplified].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansCJKSC:mode=node;+tlig;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
! Font \TU/NotoSansCJKSC(0)/m/n/10=NotoSansCJKSC:mode=node;+tlig; at 10pt not lo
adable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!


luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0

Package fontspec Warning: Font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Simplified".

luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 0

Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Chinese Simplified' not available for font
(fontspec)                'NotoSansMonoCJKSC' with script ''.

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!


luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansMonoCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}


A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



Package fontspec Info: Font family 'NotoSansMonoCJKSC(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Noto Sans Mono CJK SC' with options
(fontspec)             [WordSpace={1,0,0},HyphenChar=None,PunctuationSpace=WordS
pace,Script=Simplified,Language=Chinese
(fontspec)             Simplified].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"NotoSansMonoCJKSC:mode=node;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font
(fontspec)             =0\fontdimen 3\font \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen
(fontspec)             4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font
(fontspec)             \tex_hyphenchar:D \font =-1\scan_stop: 

luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
! Font \TU/NotoSansMonoCJKSC(0)/m/n/10=NotoSansMonoCJKSC:mode=node; at 10pt not 
loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.6 \babel@aux{chinese-simplified}{}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

)
\openout1 = test.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n on input lin
e 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/NotoSans(0)/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/NotoSansMono(0)/m/n on input line 35
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/bx/n on input li
ne 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/NotoSerif(0)/bx/it on input line 35
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/NotoSans(0)/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/NotoSansMono(0)/bx/n on input line 3
5.
 (./test.toc

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NotoSerifCJKSC(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/NotoSerifCJKSC(0)/m/n' instead on input line 5.

)
\tf@toc=\write3

\openout3 = test.toc
 [1

{c:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
```

### Question / Problem

1. Is my code correct / best practice for the intended purpose?
2. I do not get **bold** Chinese characters, although they seem to me available.
3. Strangely, even the bullet points of `itemize` changed in the Chinese part.
4. When I add `\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK SC}` (Sans Serif Chinese Font) then I get an error: `! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.`. I do not understand why (`NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf` is in the same font folder as `NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf`.).

### Update

User **David Purton** proposed the following font setup:

```
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif} 
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans} 
\babelfont{tt}{Noto Sans Mono} 
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC} 
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK SC} 
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{tt}{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}
```

Comment: 1. Your code looks OK to me. Once I add the `sf` and `tt` fonts it compiles without error or warning. 2. I do get bold Chinese (`NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc` is used from my system fonts). 3. Bullets are different for me, but perhaps you could just use `enumitem` to adjust it. 4. I don't get an error with the Sans variant (`NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc` is used from my system fonts).

Comment: You could try specifying the actual font file names instead of its family name.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks! Can you show your complete code (in an answer, incl. tt and sf, I will upvote) so that I am sure that there is no misunderstanding?

Comment: My code is exactly the same as yours. The full font set up is: `\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Noto Sans Mono}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{tt}{Noto Sans Mono CJK SC}`

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks. How do you install the fonts, on the TeXLive tree or as system fonts? And about `You could try specifying the actual font file names instead of its family name.`, how do I do that since there are so many files (bold and so on).

Comment: @DavidPurton I get several `! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.` when I use your font setup.

Comment: @DavidPurton Can I see somehow in the log file which font fiel is actually used?

Comment: See "§2.2 By File Name" in the `fontspec` manual to load fonts with more precision than you get by just giving the family (in this case `fontspec` guesses a lot). The syntax is `\babelfont[babel settings]{family}[fontspec settings]{base font file name}`

Comment: LuaLaTeX outputs which fonts are used to the console. For me it is a mix of system fonts and fonts in the TeX tree.

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks. Are you willing to generate an answer incl. the proposal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments, it turns out that you copied the CJK fonts into your main TeXLive tree. TeX can't find them unless they are indexed though.

You can either load the fonts by filename (see below), or install the fonts in your local texmf tree.

You can find this by running:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

The fonts should likely go in

```
$TEXMFHOME/fonts/opentype/google/notocjksc/
```

TeX can find these automatically. You can confirm this by running

```
`kpsewhich NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf`
```

and the font full path should be returned.

For loading the fonts by file name, you can use:

```
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}[
  Path = C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/google/notocjksc/ ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold]{NotoSerifCJKsc}

\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}[
  Path = C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/google/notocjksc/ ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold]{NotoSansCJKsc}

\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{tt}[
  Path = C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/google/notocjksc/ ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc}
```

Comment: Seems to work! Thanks.

Comment: It's meant to be faster to load by file name under LuaTeX as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question, that I installed the `notocjksc` fonts manually from CTAN.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ooooh! Did you run `mktexlsr` so that TeX knows about the files? Does `kpsewhich NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf` return anything? What about `kpsewhich NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf`?

Comment: I think manually installed packages are not meant to go in the main TeX tree anyway.

Comment: `kpsewhich NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf` does not return anything (also no error). Do you know where I should put the fonts? Since it partly worked so far, I had no reason to think that is is a mistake :)

Comment: I will be damned! I just tried `mktexlsr` on a console (`cmd`) with admin privileges and now it seems to work without specifying the font file and so on. I used the TeXLive GUI and updated everything I could find before.

Comment: I will upvote some of your other answers to thank you.

Comment: Thx for the update!