# “Package isodate Error: Isodate definition file russian.idf not found.” when trying to use Russian as \foreignlanguage

Tags: babel, cyrillic, russian

I try to use Russian in a `\foreignlanguage` entry.
So here is what I e.g. write:

```
\foreignlanguage{russian}{Федеральная служба по надзору в сфере связи, информационных технологий и массовых коммуникаций}
```

Now, as my main document contains several other languages (main language is German), I'll add this to `babel` and `isodate`:

```
\usepackage[norsk, english, german, russian, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[norsk, english, german, russian, ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
```

And I need to install `texlive-babel-russian` (or similar depending on your Tex distro)

Also, of course my document always uses UTF-8:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered, leveldown}
% unicode
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
```

However, i get this error (and I don't get this one for any other language):

> ! Package isodate Error: Isodate definition file russian.idf not found.
>
> See the isodate package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...
>
> l.79 \ProcessOptions*
>
> Maybe you misspelled the language option?

**Edit:**
If I look in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/isodate` there is indeed no definition for Russian in there.

So I've just removed `russian` from `isodate` it compiles, at least.

However it can still not display any characters in Russian?

Comment: Does it help not to pass `russian` as an option to `isodate`? I.e. `\usepackage[norsk, english, german, ngerman]{isodate}`. I wouldn't have thought you need it unless you want to print the date in Russian.

Comment: Probably not directly related, but still important: If you are running LuaLaTeX you should absolutely drop `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. With LuaLaTeX `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` is pretty pointless since LuaLaTeX assumes UTF-8 input anyway.

Comment: For proper Russian typesetting with LuaLaTeX you need a font that has Cyrillic characters. When I need Cyrillic for examples on this site I usually say `\usepackage{libertinus}`, which loads Libertinus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) and I noticed, removing `russian`from `isodate` prevents this one error.

To then actually see the chars, you still need to [select a proper font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/835/98645) though.

Fortunately, in LuaLaTex and new babel versions, it seems you can [let babel select it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530974/98645) depending on the language.

You may thus just add this in your preamble:

```
\babelfont[russian]{rm}{CMU Serif} % DejaVu Serif, FreeSerif, Linux Libertine
```

It automatically selects the font for the given language.

CMU is the „Computer Modern Unicode” and you may need to install it separately, e.g. as the package `texlive-cm-unicode` in Fedora.